# Reduce multiple bands in grouped classes with single reducer in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to reduce multiple continuous bands with a single reducer but each, grouped with a categorical image. To accomplish this I have the following structure...

```py
continuos_bands = [
  "ndmi", 
  "msavi",
  "nir",
]

result = (image.select(continuos_bands)
        .addBands(categorical_image.selfMask())
        .reduceRegion(**{
            "reducer": ee.Reducer.mean().repeat(3).group(3),
            "geometry": studyArea,
            "maxPixels": 1e19,
            "bestEffort": True,
        })
)
```

The dictionary below is just a subset and example of the result. The thing is that I do not know what is the order of the results in each class ("group"), I have three values, but are not in the same order as the input bands (my actual problem has 11 bands)... is there a way to get this order? am I missing something?

```py
...
'max': {
    'groups': [
        {'group': 2,
            'max': [
                5140.46337890625,
                0.8194190553638236,
                4851,
             ]
         }
    ]
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this, but perhaps you could use `forEachBand()` instead of `repeat()`?

```
ee.Reducer.mean().forEachBand(image).group(3)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/00294ec8f14a9ac5c05af02f4b17b2b1

Comment: that actually worked. I couldn't reproduce it either with your example (perhaps because is not complex), but the result in this way is clearer. Thanks.